# Applying styles to tables with Twitter Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Does anyone know if it is possible to apply styles on tables with Twitter Bootstrap? I can see some table examples in some older tutorials but not on the Bootstrap site itself.

I've tried to set it up but the tables in my page have almost no styling applied to them.

```html
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>#</th>
            <th>First Name</th>
            <th>Last Name</th>
            <th>Language</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>Some</td>
            <td>One</td>
            <td>English</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>Joe</td>
            <td>Sixpack</td>
            <td>English</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

What classes do I need to apply?

Answer (score 179, accepted):

Bootstrap offers various table styles. Have a look at [Base CSS - Tables](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#tables) for documentation and examples.

The following style gives great looking tables:

```html
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-condensed">
  ...
</table>
```

Answer (score 31):

Twitter bootstrap tables can be styled and well designed. You can style your table just adding some classes on your table and it’ll look nice.  You might use it on your data reports, showing information, etc.

[image]
You can use :

```
basic table
Striped rows
Bordered table
Hover rows
Condensed table
Contextual classes
Responsive tables
```

Striped rows Table :

```
    <table class="table table-striped" width="647">
    <thead>
    <tr>
    <th>#</th>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Address</th>
    <th>mail</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>Thomas bell</td>
    <td>Brick lane, London</td>
    <td>thomas@yahoo.com</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td height="29">2</td>
    <td>Yan Chapel</td>
    <td>Toronto Australia</td>
    <td>Yan@yahoo.com</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>Pit Sampras</td>
    <td>Berlin, Germany</td>
    <td>Pit @yahoo.com</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>
```

Condensed table :

Compacting a table you need to add class class=”table table-condensed” .

```
    <table class="table table-condensed" width="647">
    <thead>
    <tr>
    <th>#</th>
    <th>Sample Name</th>
    <th>Address</th>
    <th>Mail</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>Thomas bell</td>
    <td>Brick lane, London</td>
    <td>thomas@yahoo.com</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td height="29">2</td>
    <td>Yan Chapel</td>
    <td>Toronto Australia</td>
    <td>Yan@yahoo.com</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>Pit Sampras</td>
    <td>Berlin, Germany</td>
    <td>Pit @yahoo.com</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td colspan="3" align="center"></td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>
```

Ref : http://twitterbootstrap.org/twitter-bootstrap-table-example-tutorial

Answer (score 10):

You can also apply TR classes: info, error, warning, or success.

Answer (score 8):

Just another good looking table. I added "table-hover" class because it gives a nice hovering effect.

```
   <h3>NATO Phonetic Alphabet</h3>    
   <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-condensed table-hover">
   <thead>
    <tr> 
        <th>Letter</th>
        <th>Phonetic Letter</th>

    </tr>
    </thead>
  <tr>
    <th>A</th>
    <th>Alpha</th>

  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>B</td>
    <td>Bravo</td>

  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>C</td>
    <td>Charlie</td>

  </tr>

</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

bootstrap provides various classes for table

```
 <table class="table"></table>
 <table class="table table-bordered"></table>
 <table class="table table-hover"></table>
 <table class="table table-condensed"></table>
 <table class="table table-responsive"></table>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can Add contextual classes to every single row as follows:

```
<tr class="table-success"></tr>
<tr class="table-error"></tr>
<tr class="table-warning"></tr>
<tr class="table-info"></tr>
<tr class="table-danger"></tr>
```

You can also add them to table data same as above

You can set your table size by setting classes as **table-sm** and so on.

You can add custom classes and add your own styling:

```
<table class="table">
  <thead style = "color:red;background-color:blue">
    <tr>
      <th></th>
      <th>First Name</th>
      <th>Last Name</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>   
      <td>Asdf</td>
      <td>qwerty</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

This way you can add custom styling. I have showed inline styling just for example how it works, you can add classes and call them in your css as well.